# Can't install inkscape

Tags: 11.10, installation, graphics, compiling, inkscape

I tried to install several packages older ones too.Tried to upgrade it from terminal,to compile it.Once I did it and wait it for long time,but at the end of instalation it showed me 2 errors.When I'm trying to run it from terminal with `sudo inkscape` I'm getting this message.

> inkscape: error while loading shared libraries: libgtkmm-2.4.so.1:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I tried to download inkscape with synaptic and ubuntu center too.Inkscape is awesome graphic tool,but I don't see how I could make it to work on Ubuntu 11.10.Thanx in advance.

Comment: Any reason you're running it under sudo?

Answer (score 6):

This [bugreport](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/inkscape/+bug/842564) suggests to do the following:

```
 sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a
```

Please try this and see if it fixes your problem

Also, please don't run the `inkscape` command with `sudo` :)

Comment: Thanx a lot,your advice helped me to run inkscape from unity dashboard finaly.It was heavy,but as new ubuntu user I learned a lot while I was searching the solution to install inkscape.Again thanx a lot.Ubuntu developers made beautiful and very fast OS Ubuntu 11.10

Comment: Glad to hear it solved your problem. You can accept this answer then so the question is no longer marked as unanswered.

Comment: This answer is still valid on Ubuntu 16.04 (xenial) with Inkscape 0.92.1

Comment: Not on 18.04 though